# implement context menu with wxformbuilder in python

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am making an application with wxformbuilder 3.10.1, Python 3.9.12. I am trying to implement a context menu.
After reading https://wiki.wxpython.org/PopupMenuRevised I am missing any EVT_CONTEXT_MENU in the generated source code. I think somehow, I have to make a line `"self.Bind( wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU ,...)` appear in the `#Connect Events` section in the generated code. Maybe I'm just too confused..., but I don't see any means to this.
In wxFormBuilder in the properties of the Frame there is a check box "context_menu" with an explanation "generates event handler for...". But nothing changes in the generated source wether this box is checked or not. And there is no ...EVT_CONTEXT...-entry in the "Events"-tab for this object.

Possible work-aroung could be to subclass the element and add the `self.Bind( wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU ,...)` there. But the presence of the context_menu-check box tells me this is probably an odd approach.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly: context menu is just a menu. See the link for the events https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.MenuItem.html

Comment: @Axel, its possible wxFB have a bug in this regard. Or maybe something else needs to be turned on in the wxFB?